# SERVER_NAME not working on meta og:image for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags

I have a problem here with meta og:image for facebook.
I use:

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
```

to get the website url...

and in html:

```
echo"<meta property='og:image' content='$url$cover'/>";
```

this `$cover` is the image url `imgfolder/image.jpg`.

The problem here is that, facebook does not see this $url variable. In my source code it is ok, but facebook meta og:image only works if I type the url there:

```
echo"<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.myurl.com/$cover'/>";
```

But my website can't have a fixed url like this...

What is wrong? Why facebook can't see the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ?

thank you friends.

Comment: What do you mean by `facebook does not see this $url variable`?

Comment: developers.facebook tool tell me that the url is invalid and show only the imgfolder part, not the $url one...

Comment: Check if `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is set.

Comment: but everything is ok if I type the url, not using $_server

Comment: it is ok and in my source code I can see the correct url... I think facebook can't see the $_SERVER, maybe because it access the website using a different way... i dont know

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<meta property='og:image' content='" . $url . $cover . "'/>";
```